# Dataframe.shape very slow on medium size data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working with a decent amount of Twitter data (1.5 million tweets, ~4G of data) and I am trying to do some quick and dirty data exploration. Below is my code, my goal for this block of code is to find rows where the field 'text' isn't null. I'm doing a count with df.shape as a first step. However, this fairly straight-forward task is taking longer than expected to complete. Do you guys have any suggestions on how I can improve my code to get results faster? Thanks in advance.

```
def is_json(myjson):
    try:
        json_object = json.loads(myjson)
    except ValueError as e:
        return False
    return True
    
#this function opens and reads a json file while filtering out non-valid 
#JSON formats with the is_json function

with open ('json_test_file.txt') as data_file:
    data = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(line) for line in data_file if is_json(line))

#this only takes rows with 'text' field not null
df = data[pd.notnull(data['text'])]

print(df.shape)
```

Comment: what is the structure of the json? Why are you loading it a line at a time?

Comment: @EdChum: Thanks for the reply! The format is a nested json, for example: {"a":"a1", "b":"b1", "c": {"d":"d1", "e":"e2", etc}, etc}. I'm loading it one at a time because certain items in the data is not in valid JSON format and I want to weed those out using the is_json function. Should I do it a different way?

Comment: Apart from the fact that you're loading it line by line, note that for any valid JSON line, you call `json.loads()` twice (once in the comprehension and once in `is_json()`.

Comment: Hard to say what you should do exactly without knowing how the file is formatted, but it's probably good to know that Pandas has a `read_json` function now: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/io.html#io-json-reader

Comment: @RafG Ah I see, those two json.loads() must be the cause of it. I'll see if I can find an easier way to check for invalid JSON entries.